# How to define a one-way one-to-one relationship in Laravel (5.4) Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Think I'm missing something obvious here, but I want to define a one way, one to one relationship from table_1 to table_2, e.g. table1 schema:

```
    Schema::create('table1', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // Some field definitions
        $table->integer('table2_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('table2_id')->references('id')->on('table2')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Table 2 doesn't know anything about Table 1, so just has a bunch of fields defined. Model for Table 1 has:

```
public function table2() // Get table2 record
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Table2');
    }
```

Questions:

a.) Is that relationship in the record necessary just to be able to lookup the relevant table2 record from a table1 record?

b.) How do I set the relationship in my code? Currently my controller code is:

```
$table_1_record = new Table1();
// What code here to define the relationship, using Eloquent? Or do I just do:
$table_1_record->table2_id = my_table2_record->id;
// But this just sets it manually doesn't it, rather than using Eloquent?
```

Thing that is confusing me is in here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one a bit further down from the link, where it says

> Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the
>   model name. In this case, the Phone model is automatically assumed to
>   have a user_id foreign key.

Applying that example to my code, the thing is I don't want to have to define a table1_id in my Table_2 - but sounds from that quote from the docs that I need to, to find a table2 record from table1...?

c.) Is there any point in this line in the migration: `$table->foreign('table2_id')->references('id')->on('table2')->onDelete('cascade');` and indeed using Eloquent at all (I want to do things the proper Laravel way), or shall I just simply manually set table2_id as in question b.) above?

Note: I don't want to define the inverse of the relationship, as I don't need to find a table_1 record from a table_2 record.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: " I don't want to have to define a table1_id in my Table_2" How you are going to define the relation? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You have a weird case, maybe you just need to move all columns to a single table. Are you sure that you need a one-to-one relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationships in Eloquent only work in the directions that they are defined. If you want to be able to find `Table2` based on the foreign key defined in `Table1`, you would add a relationship to the `Table1` model only. You do not need to define relationships on both models in order to go one direction.

Given your `table1` schema, you are actually using the *inverse* of a one-to-one relationship. `table1` is considered a child of `table2`. Your relationship would look like this:

```
class Table1
{
    public function table2()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Table2::class);
    }
}
```

As for setting the relationship, my recommendation is to simply apply the ID from `table2` manually when creating the initial record:

```
`$table1->table2_id = $table2->id;`
```

If you're updating a `Table1` record, you can use `associate()`. [More info on that here in the docs.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) Note that this does require you to define the other side of the relationship on `Table2`. If you don't want to do that, just update the column manually when updating also.

Keep in mind that all of this is powered by Eloquent. Just because you're defining a column value manually instead of using a relationship helper method doesn't mean you're doing something ineffectively or incorrectly.

> Is there any point in [the foreign key] line in the migration

This creates a foreign key constraint in the database software itself, and has nothing to do with Eloquent. Eloquent doesn't use or care if you have a foreign key defined. There are benefits to using foreign keys, though, and suggest you look into it further to determine if they're a good idea for your application.

Comment: By the way, what does the '::class' do on the end of the belongsTo relationship? I haven't seen that before, Laravel docs examples seem to omit it. Thanks

Comment: It's a way to [get a string of the fully qualified class name](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) (fully qualified means the full namespace + class name). `\App\Table2::class` is equivalent to `'\App\Table2'`, though some editors can find references of `::class` and NOT the latter string. So I recommend it. :) You're welcome!